# How to customize "My Top Rated" playlist in Rhythmbox on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, rhythmbox

I am currently on Ubuntu 14.04 using Gnome desktop. The "My Top Rated" playlist on Rhythmbox seems to only include songs rated **** (4 stars) and above only. How do I customize this? In earlier versions of Ubuntu I was able to customize this using the Menu but don't seem to be able to do that in this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is now hidden away in the playlist button available when you click on the My Top Rated playlist.

Pictures paint a thousand words -

[image]

this will open the following window where you can click on the stars field -

[image]

As you can see I've changed from the standard 4 stars to 2 stars.  Click Close to save your settings.

Comment: Thanks! I kept looking online but couldn't find anything. Another example of why consistent UI is important.